# How to perform a local shell command in OpenStack HOT template file?

Tags: openstack, heat, openstack-heat

The user data section in HOT is to run shell command on new created nova instance, however, I want to run a local(the machine which runs heat stack-create command) shell command when perform "heat stack-create" command.

But after I read though the OpenStack HOT doc, I didn't find any syntax to support this.

Comment: You can achieve it by having your own heat plugin and invoke it by calling something like OS::Gemfield::RunShellCmd.

Comment: This will be an issue when deploy HOT template file to other OpenStack host, due to lack of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax to support this.  Heat templates are processed *on the server*.  There is also no guarantee that the submitting system even has a standard Unix shell (heat templates can be submitted via a web browser, or with tools other than the `heat` CLI).

If your deployment workflow requires coordinating some local action with the Heat deployment, your best bet is to use another tool (Ansible?  A shell script?) to automate the workflow.

An alternative would be to have Heat (or your VMs) signal your local system using some sort of web hook, and have a web service running locally that would receive the signal and perform whatever action is appropriate.